# Would the sequence be convergent and would $U$ be contained in $W$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real sequences.

1. Prove that $W = \Big\{ (a_n) \in V: a_n=0 \Big\}$ is a subspace of $V$.
2. Prove that $U = \Big\{ (a_n) \in V: \text{the summation of $a_n^2$ is finite} \Big\}$ is a subspace of $V$. Also show that $U$ is contained in $W$.

I solved the first question. But I could not solve the second part. I think if $(a_n) \in U$ then it might be convergent. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: I suggest that you use mathjax for your question. it might be hard to understand if you write it like this

Comment: Is it available for android too?

Answer (score 1):

I would first show that $U\subset W$ and then that $U$ is a subspace of V.

- If $a_n\in U$, let's suppose that $a_n$ doesn't tend to $0$.

Then $\exists\epsilon>0,\exists(n_k)\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} s.t. \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, |a_n|>\epsilon$

But then $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n^2\geqslant\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} a_{n_k}^2>\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \epsilon = +\infty$, which contradicts $a_n\in U$. Hence $U\subset W$

- Let $(a_n),(b_n)\in U, \lambda,\mu \in\mathbb{R}$

You have to show that $(\lambda a_n + \mu b_n) \in U$.

$\forall n, (\lambda a_n + \mu b_n)^2=\lambda^2 a_n^2 + \mu^2 b_n^2 +2\lambda\mu a_n b_n$

Let's majorate each of these three terms by the general term of a sommable sequence. I think you can work it out by yourself for the two first terms. For the third one, you can use the first point: $U\subset W$, so $b_n\rightarrow 0$, so for $n$ big enough, $|a_nb_n|<|a_n|$...

Can you take on from there ?

Comment: I guess so. Thanks (y)